# Ad-words Average order value and Max CPC [API]

Tags: google-ads-api

I am pulling data from Adwords report API. I can get everything that I need clicks, impressions, position for my keyword. But there are two things what I can't find in those:

1. Average order value.
2. Max CPC (hourly)

Could you please recommend me where I can get this date I need.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query item MaxCpc was changed within the last year or so. It was replaced with the query item CpcBid. I'm not sure what to do about order value, but the documentation containing all of the query items for the different report types can be found at:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports
Hope this helps!